# querySelectorAll not selecting elements within shadowRoot

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-component

I’m trying to create a `tic-tac-toe game` using `Webpack` and `Web Component`.

I need to select a `div` tag having `cell` class within `shadowRoot` at `place-mark` component, then update `innerText` to O/X depending on Turn calculated by another function.

The logic is working fine but I cannot select the right components to update the HTML view, so the user could see current status of the selected areas.

Here's my simplified HTML code:

```html
<div class="board" id="board">
    <place-mark data-cell></place-mark>
</div>
```

Here’s my simplified component code:

```js
const template = document.createElement("template");

template.innerHTML = `<div class="cell" />`;

export default class PlaceMark extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(
            template.content.cloneNode(true)
        );
    }
}

window.customElements.define(
    "place-mark",
    PlaceMark
);
```

Here’s my simplified JS code:

```js
const X_CLASS = "x";
const CIRCLE_CLASS = "circle";
const cellElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-cell]');
const board = document.getElementById("board");
let circleTurn;

function startGame() {
    cell.addEventListener("click", handleClick, { once: true });});
}

function handleClick(e) {
    const cell = e.target;
    const currentClass = circleTurn
        ? CIRCLE_CLASS
        : X_CLASS;
    placeMark(cell, currentClass);
    if (checkWin(currentClass)) {
        endGame(false);
    } else if (isDraw()) {
        endGame(true);
    } else {
        swapTurns();
        setBoardHoverClass();
    }
}

function placeMark(cell, currentClass) {
    cell.classList.add(currentClass);
}
```

If you need full version of codes above, Here's my project:

https://github.com/nazaninsnr/TicTacToe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply remove `shadowRoot` from your code

it would give you the chance to have access to all the elements and `querySelect` what you want.

```
export default class PlaceMark extends HTMLElement {
constructor() {
super();
this.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));}}
window.customElements.define("place-mark", PlaceMark);
```

Answer (score 0):

global `querySelector` code can **not** access DOM content **within** shadowRoots.

If you have an `open` shadowRoot, you can do:
`document.querySelector("my-component").shadowRoot("[data-cell]")`

This will ofcourse get hairy when you have **nested** shadowRoots.

**You might want to change your logic to:**

- The board emits an **Event**
- The 9 tiles listen for the **Event**, and act accordingly

working SO Snippet below:

- click a tile to emit a `tileclicked` Event
- `<my-board>` listens for this Event
- and emits one Event `colortile`
- **all 9 tiles** listen for the `colortile` Event
- each tile changes its color

```html
<my-board></my-board>
<hr>
<my-board></my-board>

<script>
  class GameComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(html){
      super().attachShadow({mode: "open"}).innerHTML = html;
    }
    dispatch({ from = this,eventname,detail = {} }) {
      from.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(eventname, {
        composed: true, bubbles: true, detail
      }));
    }
    listen({at = this,eventname,func }) {
      at.addEventListener(eventname, func);
    }
  }
  customElements.define("my-board", class extends GameComponent {
    constructor() {
      super(`<style>:host{display:grid;grid:20px/repeat(3,60px);gap:1px}</style>` +
        "green,red,blue,orange,olive,tan,teal,yellow,lime"
        .split(",").map(color => `<my-tile>${color}</my-tile>`).join(""));
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.listen({ at:this, eventname:"tileclicked",
                    func: (evt) => {
                          //console.log(evt.target,evt.composedPath());
                          this.dispatch({ from: this, eventname: "colortile",
                                          detail: { color: evt.detail.color }})}})
    }
  });
  customElements.define("my-tile", class extends GameComponent {
    constructor() {
      super(`<style>:host{text-align:center;cursor:pointer}</style><slot></slot>`);
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.onclick = () => this.dispatch({ from: this, eventname: "tileclicked",
                                           detail: { color: this.innerText }});
      this.listen({
                   at: this.getRootNode().host.closest("my-board"),
                   eventname: "colortile",
                   func: (evt) => this.style.background = evt.detail.color });
    }
  });
</script>
```

**Playground: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/Lk9r4gx2/**

**Notes:**

- in practice I would not set a shadowDOM on `<my-tile>`; then The `<my-board>` STYLE can style all tiles. And you can use `MY-BOARD.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll`
- you also do not need `getRootNode()` then to *escape* shadowRoot, and find the `closest("my-board")`
- experiment with the disabled `console.log` to learn how events get re-targeted, and `composedPath` then saves your ...
- Its JavaScript, you can pass a Function **reference** in that `detail:{}` property bag... that way a Tile can access **methods** on the Board, or vice versa.